# Adding Double quotes to last value

Tags: unix

I have the data in below format.

```
abc ssg,"-149,684.58","-149,469.05",-215.53
efg sfg,-80.99,-77.46,-3.53
hij sf,"4,341.23","4,131.90",209.33
kilm mm,"2,490,716.13","-180,572.48","9,223.06"
```

I want to add double quotes to those value at the end which does not have double quotes done through perl or unix

the output should look as below:

```
abc ssg,"-149,684.58","-149,469.05","-215.53"
efg sfg,-80.99,-77.46,"-3.53"
hij sf,"4,341.23","4,131.90","209.33"
kilm mm,"2,490,716.13","-180,572.48","9,223.06"
```

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
gawk -F ',' -v Q='"' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} $NF !~ Q {gsub(/.*/,Q $NF Q,$NF); print ; next} 1' INPUTFILE
```

1. `-F ','` sets the input field separator
2. `-v Q='"'` sets the `Q` variable to `"`, this helps to avoid some escaping problems
3. `BEGIN {OFS=FS}` set the output field separator to the same as the input
4. `$NF !~ Q` if the last field not matches `Q` (`=="`) then
5. `gsub(/.*/,Q $NF Q,$NF)` replace the last field to `"` delimited
6. `print` the line
7. skip the `next` rule(s) and process the next line
8. `1` executes the default print line action for every other line (where the last field not matches `"`)